# Installing mesos egg for python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, api, ubuntu, mesos

I've installed mesos 0.26 successfully on a vm machine.
The installation has been performed on an ubuntu trusty thar system 
by following this manual: 
https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/

So far so good. I wanted to write a tiny python framwork.
For this I need to install the eggs via easy_install:
(I've downloaded the eggs accordingly for the trusty thar ubuntu and the 0.26 mesos):

wget http://downloads.mesosphere.io/master/ubuntu/14.04/mesos-0.26.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
easy_install mesos-0.26.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

all went fine, however, if I start python in the shell
and type in

```
import mesos.interface
```

I get the message: ImportError: No module named interface

As someone suggested, it may be that there is no longer a binding for python, or that they have renamed the API calls. Well, I looked in the version updates here:
http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/upgrades/

Since the transition from 0.19.x to 0.20.x there hasn't been any changes regarding the mesos.interface part, or at least they are not mentioning it here.

To increase the confusion I also get the following error message when I'm typing in python: import mesos.native
There I receive: ImportError: No module named interface.mesos_pb2. To put it into a nutshell: what is going wrong here, and how can it be fixed? And yes, I've googled various web pages, with terms such as "mesos python bindings", mesos +api +python, etc. And yes, I have also consulted the official mesos webpage. There are nice refences for Java and C++ but not for python, or at least they are very well hidden.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. For what reasons ever:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

is required to set the PYTHONPATH. After that step it works like a charm.